# removing item from arraylist java

Tags: java

I am trying to compare weather an item is contained within the arrayList and if it is then remove it. Im not sure weather I have to implement my own equals method or not, this is my code but it isn't working to remove the correct item.

```
  public boolean removeItem(Item item) {

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

        if (items.get(i).equals(item)) {
            items.remove(item);
            return true;
        } 


    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check out the `contains` and `remove` methods of `ArrayList`.

Comment: And better use iterator and remove() on iterator to avoid concurrent modification exception.

Comment: yes, you have to implement equals and hashCode for your `Item` class

Comment: I think you want `contains` not equals`. You don't even need to loop it.

Comment: @Nambari, I don't think such an exception would be possible here as Luke14 is using an "old-school" for loop instead of for each. A good principle, though!

Comment: @kviiri: you are correct. I overlooked old-school for, I will edit my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely remove items from a `Collection` using `Iterator`

```
public boolean removeItem(Item item) {    
  Iterator<Item> it = items.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
     Item i = it.next();
     if(i.equals(item)) {
       it.remove();
       // remove next line if you want to remove all occurrences `item`
       return true; 
     }      
  }
  return false;
}
```

You could also just call

```
items.remove(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayList#remove(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) will do exactly that! But this works only if you have overridden the `equals` method of `Item`.
If You want to remove all elements, will need a loop:

```
public int remove(Item item) {
    int i = 0;

    while(list.remove(item)) {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

this will return the amount of items that have been removed

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

Comment: Note that this loop will look for the elements to remove *from the start* after every item removed. It has a complexity `O(k*n)` where `k` is `list.size()` and `n` is the number `item` currencies. This could be done i `O(k)` using `list.iterator()` and `iterator.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want contains not equals`. You don't even need to loop it. That's the magic of the method.

```
public boolean removeItem(Item item) {

    if (items.contains(item)){
        items.remove(item);
    }
    return false;  // I have no idea why you want to return false.
                   // I'll just leave it there
}
```

Comment: this will always return false! `romove` is no function of arraylist

Comment: you have a typo on remove

Comment: This traverses the list twice--once for `contains()` and again for `remove()`. You might as well just call `remove()` and let it fail if the item isn't in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to override equals in your class.Compare every single attribute and when one of them dont equals the other, then return false. If you use eclipse for example, you can let it create the equals method for your class.